# Inspecting variables in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, code-inspection

I have been using Eclipse for maybe 6 years, debugging Java.  Almost always, when I halt in a class I can inspect the variables and see their values.  However, for some code, while I can step through it, when I try to inspect a variable it will say that the variable is not found.  It will say that for any variable I try to inspect.

I figure maybe it was not built with debugging turned on somehow, so I did a maven->update on all the projects in my Eclipse, and did a Run As maven->generate sources but that still did not work.

This class (though it has happened in others too) should be available to everyone.  It is
java.sql.timestamp.  That is just one class where I have noticed it.

My Eclipseinfo is

Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0)
Build id: 20181214-0600

And to repeat, i CAN step through the code, just not display variables.

Comment: By 'can't see the variables' do you mean the fields inside Timestamp? Timestamp is part of the Java runtime library so it won't be affected by your compilation options, only the options that were used when the library was built. A quick test here with the Java 16 JDK I don't have any problems. Note that Eclipse 2018-12 is now 3 years and 11 releases old.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I mean.  I figured maybe Timestamp might have that problem.  I notice in other code also.  I will pay attention each time to see if every time it happens it is with a third party class.  (We have hundreds of classes written by others in the company that we use also).